# why is my indexOf statement creating an error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use .indexOf to find out if an array contains a string. Something is causing an error, but I don't know what. I'm sure this is a **really** simple thing, but I don't know the language and so don't see it. What's wrong?

```
//this code creates an error in IE
var myMines=new Array();
var newMine="22";
var myVar = myMines.indexOf(newMine);   //when I comment out this line, the page does not generate an error
```

Comment: older IE versions don't support `indexOf` for arrays.

Comment: also, what error are you getting?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: also, does not create an error in chrome. The value for myVar, in your case, is -1

Comment: Are you actually getting an error?  Can you include that in the question?

Comment: the code doesnt generate any error on latest chrome.

Comment: P.S. The more "accepted" way to make an array is `var myMines = [];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you, by chance, using IE 8 (or lower)?  `Array.indexOf` only works in IE 9+, Firefox 3+, and Chrome 7+.

Source: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Docs for `Array.indexOf` (also includes a function to implement this in browsers that don't support it): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 3):

Before being added in some modern browsers indexOf was exclusively a function used to search a string for another string and return the starting index.  You are trying to use this function on an empty array and I'm guessing in a browser that does not support the indexOf function for arrays.

Comment: `indexOf` was added for arrays.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Using `indexOf` on an empty array will just return -1, not an error.

Answer (score 1):

All you are doing it creating an array, and then seeing if something exists in it.

newMine is simply a value that you are attempting to look for inside an empty array.  Try populating the array first.

Comment: shouldn't it just return -1 though?

Comment: This is not the error.  `indexOf` on a blank array will return -1, not an error.

Answer (score 1):

What you do is basically:

- creating an Array;
- creating a variable;
- forget to add it to the array;
- asking an array for the position of an item that is nou in the array.

Answer (score 1):

I've just posted your code into my Firebug console (running Firefox 11) and it worked. As your array is "empty" here, indexOf() just returns -1. Maybe you're script just can't handle a -1 value. However, I believe this code should work in most browsers. Who knows, maybe you've just found a bug in chrome's javascript implementation (^^).

Answer (score 0):

The `IndexOf` returns the current index/position (0 base) of a string, i.e.

```
var myMines="Hello World";
var myVar = myMines.indexOf('W');
alert(myVar); // Will alert 6 because 'W' is at the 7th position (first index is 0) so index is 6
```

Comment: `indexOf` was added for arrays.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Thanks there! A string is being converted to an array internally when indexOf being called and returns the index, as I know, Please make me clear if I'm wrong.

Comment: `indexOf` for strings and arrays have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Does that mean same indexOf works in different ways for string and array ?

Comment: I think so.  I may be wrong too.  It doesn't really matter though.

Comment: You're welcome.  I don't actually know how the internals of `indexOf` work, but it shouldn't matter to us JavaScript programmers.